How do I dodge Dooryani's Triumph's Self-Destruction Slam?
After you get the mech down to around 50% health, Doryani's Triumph; the final boss of Act 3, the giant scorpion mech starts using a move where it self-destructs after emitting a Lightning Aura.

However, I keep on getting one-shotted the slam that follows this self-destruction.

How/when do I dodge out of this slam? What is the cue to dodge, or how should I be moving?
I tried a full armour build but this is the only attack that I cannot "tank".

Try to start spamming rolls a little bit before he starts chasing you (right after his blue circle blows down) until you successfully dodge. This worked for me, but I also changed my boots to +15% movement speed when I came up with this idea, so actually I don't know what exactly this was.

This looks like you'd be able to dodge it if you went straight for the edge of the circle instead of the curved route up and then right. When the mech slows down its tracking of you, that's the cue to roll.

Straight doesn't help either. I keep to the edge, and when it stops, I make a straight dash for the edge.
